# Get text of table header and put them as select box values in jquery

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

Here i have one requirement to be done.

I have a table container with headers as like below.

[image]

All I need to do is, I want to get all the texts (User Information, location) of all table header and append the same values as select box options.  Like below

[image]

Select box is available in another div container.  How can i achieve through jQuery? Any idea?

By this jquery, I am getting alert of all header texts :

```
  $('.availabilityView tr th').each(function () { var avilCont = $('.availabilityView tr th').eq($(this).index()).text(); alert(avilCont); });
```

I want to push all alerted texts into select box container as options. Select box is placed next to the table container... Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Please post the relevant markup (we have no information at all about your table or your `<select>` element, for instance) and the code you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: While images are very useful, as an *additional* resource, and worth a thousand words, they're not very specific words, and lead to ambiguity, guesses and a lot of useless noise and speculation. Show us code: it's much easier to work with.

Comment: By this jquery, I am getting alert of all header texts :
$('.availabilityView tr th').each(function () {
                var avilCont = $('.availabilityView tr th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                alert(avilCont);
            });

I want to push all alerted texts into select box container as options.  Select box is placed next to the table container...

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Fantastic! Now, if you *show us your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) code* we can help, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8aznd3a6/)** here

HTML code:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>head1</th>
        <th>head2</th>
        <th>head3</th>
        <th>head4</th>
        <th>head5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>abc 3</td>
        <td>abc 4</td>
       <td>abc 5</td>
    </tr> 


</table>

<div>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option>--Selected--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
var headerValue = $('#mytable th');
for(var index in headerValue){
    var header = headerValue[index].innerHTML;
    if(header)
    $("#mySelect").append(new Option(header, header));
}
```